# Mysql、php、smartyを利用したサイトで情報抽出に関するsmarty、php上での記述方法

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

お世話になります。どうかご教授お願い申し上げます。

Mysql、php、smartyを利用したサイトを作成しております。Proudct_id毎に表示するページ（smarty）で、以下の様なテーブルtbl_product_checkを使用しproduct_idが同じchecker_nameをsmary側で抽出したいと考えております。

例えば、product_idが533のページではsmarty側で533（zen、joice、john）、そしてproduct_idが514のページではsmarty側で514（james、zen、joice）、同様に532では532（zen、joice）という名前（checker_name）を表示させたいのですが、それに必要となるsmarty、およびphpでの記述方法をご指導頂けませんでしょうか。

*tbl_product_check

(フィールド名)
product_checker_id
product_id
checker_name
member_id

```
        0   533 zen   190    
        1   514 james 189   
        2   533 joice 191   
        3   532 zen   190        
        4   514 zen   190        
        5   532 joice 191   
        6   514 joice 191   
        7   533 john  192
```

---

**追記**  
himakuma様、

いろいろと試しておりますが、当フレームワークの記述方法で以下の様な記述にたどり着きました。ただ機能しておりません(エラーは出ませんが、何も表示されません)。どこに問題があるかご指摘頂けませんでしょうか。

PHP：

```
$objFormParam = new SC_FormParam_Ex();
    $product_id = $objFormParam->getValue('product_id');
    $objQuery =& SC_Query_Ex::getSingletonInstance();
    $checkerName = $objQuery->getOne('SELECT checker_name FROM tbl_product_check where product_id =  ?', array($product_id)); 
    $results = array();
        foreach ($checkerName as $id) {
            $results[$id['product_id']][] = $id['product_id'];
        }
        return $results;
```

SMARTY：

```
{foreach from=$checkerName item=product_id name= checker_name}
    {$checkerName [$checker_name]}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: smarty以外のフレームワークは使用しないのですか？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。これは某ECサイトで、基本的にはテンプレート（smarty）側でphpを呼び出す形式をとっております。

Comment: smartyのテンプレートから判定用のPHPを呼び出したいということですか？？私の認識では、PHP側で処理を行いテンプレートには値を設定するというのが一般的です。(表示の制御に必要なループや判定は行う※データの抽出等はしない)後、各バージョンを教えて下さい

Comment: SSDev 様、申し訳ございません。具体的な流れは分かっておりません。一般的な方法でお願いしたいです。MySQL 5.0.95、PHP5.2.9、Apache/2.2.3、Linux p47

Comment: smartyのバージョンも教えて下さい。新規ですか？既存修正ですか？

Comment: SSDev 様、version 2.6.26　です。

Comment: 基本的には回答した内容でできます。smarty3.0の記述なので少し違う可能性はあります。

Answer (score 1):

いろいろ情報が足りてないのでざっくりとした流れだけ。。。
１．PHPで表示したいデータを取得、編集
２．Smartyへデータを渡す
３．Smarty側で表示したい形にする（プルダウン等）

※requireとかエラーの判定とかは記載してません
**■PHP**

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty();

１．PHPで表示したデータを取得、編集
$product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
$sql = "SELECT checker_name, member_id FROM tbl_product_check WHERE product_id = {$product_id}";
//PDO等でSQL発行、結果を受取smartyで使用しやすい配列等に編集
$hyouziDataList = array(
    0 => array('checker_name' => 'zen', 'member_id' => 190),
    1 => array('checker_name' => 'joice', 'member_id' => 191),
    2 => array('checker_name' => 'john', 'member_id' => 191)
);


２．Smartyへデータを渡す
$smarty->assign('hyouziDataList',$hyouziDataList);

テンプレートの表示
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
?>
```

**■Smarty**

```
{foreach from=$hyouziDataList item=hyouziData}
３．Smarty側で表示したい形にする（プルダウン等）
    <li>{$hyouziData.member_id}：{$hyouziData.checker_name}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: SSDev 様、$hyouziDataList = ※PDO等でSQL発行、結果を受取smartyで使用しやすい配列等に編集

Comment: SSDev 様、申し訳ございません。上記の再送です。”$hyouziDataList = ※PDO等でSQL発行、結果を受取smartyで使用しやすい配列等に編集”
の=の後は具体的にどのような設定にすれば宜しいのでしょうか。

Comment: 代入箇所を修正しました。実際の取得方法、編集内容は、動作が不明な為、記載できません。

Comment: 以下の記述ですが、上で紹介したMySqlのデータの情報は最初の段階では全く存在せず、徐々に半永久的に増えていくデータです。ですので、以下の様な記述を設定する段階ではデータは存在しておりません。それを踏まえて、実際の取得方法などもう少々ご説明頂けませんでしょうか。
$hyouziDataList = array(
    0 => array('checker_name' => 'zen', 'member_id' => 190),
    1 => array('checker_name' => 'joice', 'member_id' => 191),
    2 => array('checker_name' => 'john', 'member_id' => 191)
);

Comment: DBからの取得する配列の内部構成を固定で記載しただけなので、DBからの取得はPDOを使用すれば良いです。DBの接続方法がわからないのですか？？接続方法等は検索したほうが早いと思いますよ？

Comment: SSDev 様、試した結果”Class 'Smarty' not found on”というエラーがでまして、smartyのcfgフィルにある行（‘include’ => APPPATH.’vendor’.DS.’Smarty’.DS.’libs’.DS.’Smarty.class.php’, // ）を追加すればいいという内容のサイトをネット上で見つけ出したのですが、どのファイルにその行を追加すればよいか分かりかねておりました。何かご助言はありますでしょうか。

Comment: エラーの内容は分かっていますか？サイトに記載されている内容はおそらく別のフレームワークを使用していて、Smartyを読み込む為の設定です。今回はSmartyのみなので、どこに記載しても意味はありません。「require」、「include」、「require_once」で検索してみてください。PHP、Smartyのマニュアルも見てください「http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ja/」、「https://secure.php.net/manual/ja/index.php」。ＰＨＰの基本的な使用方法を理解していないように思われます。

Comment: SSDev 様、ご教授の通りいろいろと試しております。申し訳ございませんが、別のフレームワークを使用している上で今回の記述を使用しようとした場合、具体的にはどうゆう記述にすればよろしいのでしょうか。例えば、include文を使用しても同様のエラーがでます。

Comment: フレームワークを使用している場合は、フレームワーク単位で記述方法が変わります。smartyのみの場合はプレーンのPHP上から呼び出すことになるので、複数回呼出を防ぐ為に「require_once」を使用すべきだと思います。ディレクトリ構成がわからない為、記述すべき内容はわかりません。同じエラーということは指定しているファイルのパスが間違っていると思います。

Comment: himakuma様、上記の質問に追加をいたしました。目を通して頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: newしているクラスが何かも分からないので、わかりません。smartyに変数を設定している記述が無いようですが？マニュアル読みました？

Comment: returnはどこに返してるんですか？